# Image upload auto selection as base, small and thumb

Tags: image, magento-1.9, upload

I was just wondering if there is a way the image radio button auto select as base, small, thumb so I don't have to select manually every time when uploaded.
Screenshot
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why close and downvote? This is an important question!

Answer (score 5):

And to answer the question: No, magento can't do this out of the box. But you can "easily" change the JS code which adds the row to the table, so when you add the first one, the radio buttons are checked.

The creation of a row is made here: `js/mage/adminhtml/product.js:140`

Comment: Hi Fab, any idea where to look at the product.js

Comment: I think it is under `js/mage/adminhtml/product.js` without the lib.

Comment: I don't understand the question. I posted the path and the line? Damn, thanks David. Obviously I took the only project I have where someone copied the whole JS directory into lib :(

Comment: when you upload product image then the until the radio button checked the images doesn't display to the front end. I want the radio button auto checked when upload complete

Comment: @Dips, you don't need to reword your question. Fabian clearly understands what you want, and has provided you with an answer. I've just got it working thanks to his advice. True, he doesn't tell you exactly what you need to add to product.js - if you're unable to figure that part out, just say so. I've added an answer that will tell you exactly what needs to be added. But don't get used to the idea of SO doing all the work for you! :)

Answer (score 3):

To follow on from [Fabian's Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30754/4090), you need to add

```
radio.checked=true;
```

just after the line

```
radio.observe('change', this.onChangeRadio);
```

in the Product.Gallery.createImageRow function.

In Magento 1.9.0.1 this is on line 149.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Fabian and Doug for the groundwork. I just published an extension, which does exactly what you are trying to achieve in a clean way: https://github.com/customgento/CustomGento_AutoSelectImages

It simply adds a JS file on the admin product edit page. In the JS file, the mentioned method `Product.Gallery.createImageRow` is wrapped, so that the radio buttons can be selected after the first image has been uploaded. Here is the JS "magic":

```
if (typeof Product.Gallery !== 'undefined') {
    Product.Gallery.prototype.createImageRow = Product.Gallery.prototype.createImageRow.wrap(function (parentMethod, image) {
        // first call the parent method
        parentMethod(image);

        // auto-select the radio buttons for the first uploaded image
        $H(this.imageTypes).each(function (pair) {
            if (this.images.length === 1) {
                this.getFileElement(image.file, 'cell-' + pair.key + ' input').checked = true;
            }
        }.bind(this));
        this.setProductImages(image.file);
    });
}
```